# Adobe Flash Player problem

Tags: firefox, flash-player

In both Firefox and Internet Explorer, on the web page [DeadMau5](http://www.myspace.com/deadmau5) I see this message:

"**Get Flash now!** In order to listen or view this content you will have to upgrade your version of Flash."
There is download button taking me to the Adobe site. The latest version is 10.0.42.34.

The trouble is, I already have the latest version of Flash. Revo Uninstaller shows that I have Adobe Flash Player 10 ActiveX version 10.0.42.34, and Adobe Flash Player 10 Plugin version 10.0.42.34.

I have used the official Adobe Flash uninstaller. I have restarted several times. I have tried everything. I have emptied the cache. I have cleared all the cookies; I have cleared all the Flash cookies.

BTW, this happens on only one computer. My other computer (with the same version of Flash) displays the content properly.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the same thing happens on other sites, I would try uninstalling the plugin and re-installing it, I usually go with the firefox add-on, seems to download and install faster.

If it's only the one website, it probably is an issue on their part, they might have an old version of flash that doesn't recognise your newer version.